# Jquery to check checkboxes in similar DIVs

Tags: jquery

I need some help using Jquery to loop through 2 similar DIV's individually, check if the checkboxes are checked and build a CVS list of ID's of those that are.  I do this in other places, but the fact that these are so similary named and must call the same function, I cannot figure it out.

Below are samples of the 2 DIV's and their checkboxes.  Onclick, they call the function "selectTag".  Here is where I need to determine which of the 2 DIV's holds the checkbox that was clicked, loop through only that DIV, see if they are checked and build a comma seperated list of ID's.  Checking an item in the first DIV cannot loop through and check the items in the second DIV and vice versa.

It's worth noting I cannot change the function call or much of the HTML although I did add the "data-tag-container" to try something.  I was able to do this and it seems to get both DIVs but I cannot figure out how to loop though either:

```js
function selectTag(parent, value, text) {
  console.log(parent, value, text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rb_shell" id="divTagGroup14" data-tag-container>
  <div class="rb_title">Nexxus</div>
  <div id="divTagGroupItems14">
    <div class="rb_UnSelectedItem">
      <label for="inputdivTag7">
    <input name="Tag" id="inputdivTag7" type="radio" value="7" onchange="selectTag(this.parentNode, '7', 'Financial Nexxus');" />Financial Nexxus</label>
    </div>
    <div class="rb_UnSelectedItem">
      <label for="inputdivTag8"><input name="Tag" id="inputdivTag8" type="radio" value="8" onchange="selectTag(this.parentNode, '8', 'Driving Nexxus');" />Driving Nexxus</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="rb_shell" id="divTagGroup15" data-tag-container>
  <div class="rb_title">Funds</div>
  <div id="divTagGroupItems15">
    <div class="rb_UnSelectedItem">
      <label for="inputdivTag9">                     
    <input name="Tag" id="inputdivTag9" type="radio" value="9" onchange="selectTag(this.parentNode, '9', 'Appropriated');" />Appropriated</label>
    </div>
    <div class="rb_UnSelectedItem">
      <label for="inputdivTag10">                     
    <input name="Tag" id="inputdivTag10" type="radio" value="10" onchange="selectTag(this.parentNode, '10', 'Non-Appropriated'); " />Non-Appropriated</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not opposed to looping through all them on each click but they must build 2 separate CVS lists of ID's based on their DIV and place them in a textbox.

```
var objTest = $('[data-tag-container]');

objTest.children('input').each(function() {
  //alert(this.value); // "this" is the current element in the loop
  alert("hello");
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what are the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to determine which of the 2 DIV's holds the checkbox that was clicked, loop through only that DIV, see if they are checked and build a comma seperated list of ID's.

In your current sample there is only a single radio group per DIV, so there can only ever be a single checked item. I suppose in your real HTML there are multiple radio groups per DIV.

```js
$(document).on("click", "div[data-tag-container] :radio", function () {
  // build a CSV list, or whatever you plan to do.
  $(this).closest("div[data-tag-container]").find(":checked").each(function () {
    console.log(this.value, $(this).parent("label").text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rb_shell" id="divTagGroup14" data-tag-container>
  <div class="rb_title">Nexxus</div>
  <div id="divTagGroupItems14">
    <div class="rb_UnSelectedItem">
      <label><input name="Tag" type="radio" value="7">Financial Nexxus</label>
    </div>
    <div class="rb_UnSelectedItem">
      <label><input name="Tag" type="radio" value="8">Driving Nexxus</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="rb_shell" id="divTagGroup15" data-tag-container>
  <div class="rb_title">Funds</div>
  <div id="divTagGroupItems15">
    <div class="rb_UnSelectedItem">
      <label><input name="Tag" type="radio" value="9">Appropriated</label>
    </div>
    <div class="rb_UnSelectedItem">
      <label><input name="Tag" type="radio" value="10">Non-Appropriated</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, they are checkboxes, not radiobuttons.  There's code that converts them that I didn't run them through beforehand.

Comment: @Mark That changes next to nothing about the code above, other than `:radio` to `:checkbox`.

Comment: (And for your next question, please post a code sample that pays attention to those details. It's hard to follow a moving target when it comes to solving programming problems.)